# Is there a way to set auto refresh the jetpack compose preview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I just started to use the Jetpack compose toolkit. I added the `@Preview` and a set `showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true` as parameters and it works really good. But every time i add or change something it doesn't auto refresh by itself, so i have to do it manually.

Comment: No, you are wrong. Refresh is going, but only some properties, such as text or color.

Comment: Any luck finding the answer to this?
Tip: Use the keyboard shortcut, It at least makes it faster. 
For mac: ⌥⇧⌘R (option + Shift + Command + R)

Comment: As of now, hot refresh is only available for primitive values I guess

Answer (score 1):

as Raul text, padding and some other things update automatically, but  **

> make sure you have live edit of literals on

**.

But soon Live edit of composables, not just literals (Int, String, Dp...) will be available, :
[read more here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling)

Answer (score 0):

for the static resources like text, color the UI updates automatically, as it does on the running application, but for the structural components you need to rebuild the project and the changes apply automatically in the preview as well.

Answer (score -1):

Some Components auto-refresh on version 1.1.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31303844)